# How to display an error message before redirecting in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to display an error alert before redirecting to another function. I use following code,

```
if($num1==$num2) {
   $message = "Incorrect input";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    redirect('my_contr/first');
}
```

If I comment the line of redirecting line alert works fine, but need to alert before redirecting.

please help me to modify this to a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use client side redirect (javascripy) add window.location() insted of php redirect()

```
if($num1==$num2) {
   $message = "Incorrect input";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');window.location = ('my_contr/first') </script>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle error messages is to set a variable $error_message that I display in my views when isset($error_message) == true

```
$data['error_message'] = '<strong>Warning !</strong> An error has occurred.';
....
$this->load->view('my_contr/first', $data);
```